# При попытке делать sudo apt-get update выдает 403 Forbidden

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update, apt

Я пользуюсь VM на Oracle. Там стоит Ubuntu 22.04, прежде делал подобную команду и все работало. Но не так давно была необходимость снова обновить, но заметил там ошибку.

````
```
Сущ:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Сущ:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                   
Сущ:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                                  
Пол:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                                                            
Ошб:5 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy InRelease                                                   
  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.9.44.123 443]
Пол:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11,4 kB]         
Пол:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10,1 kB]
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово                
E: Не удалось получить https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/dists/jammy/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 65.9.44.123 443]
E: Репозиторий «https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com jammy InRelease» не подписан.
N: Обновление из этого репозитория нельзя выполнить безопасным способом, поэтому по умолчанию он отключён.
N: Информацию о создании репозитория и настройках пользователя смотрите в справочной странице apt-secure(8).
```
````

Искал много вариантов как решить проблему, но пока не один не сработал.

Comment: Разобрался сам. В папке /etc/apt/sources.list.d нашел файл hashicorp и удалил его. После все обновилось.

Answer (score 0):

Да, если просто пройти по ссылке

`https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com/dists/jammy/InRelease`

получаем ответ

```
403 ERROR

The request could not be satisfied.

The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
```

Так что вы правильно сделали, что удалили этот файл